# How do I use JQL to list all Epics that have no stories(empty Epics]?

Tags: jira

I want to list out all the Epics with no stories in Jira. How can I achieve it? I don't have ScriptRunner or any other add-ons. I am trying to do it with JQL.
I tried the following and I got 0 results.

```
project = XYZ AND issuetype = Epic AND "Epic Link" is Empty
project = XYZ AND "Story Points" <=  0 AND  issuetype = Epic
```

Answer (score 0):

"**Epic Link**" is used to know if an issue has an Epic. But you can't use it in the inverse sense.

You can't do that with the jira standard features.

You can do that by using the JQL **(issueFunction not in hasLinkType("Epic-Story Link"))**. But you should have **ScriptRunner** installed on your instance to use it.